# How to send localnotification when my location is update in suspended mode in ios?

Tags: ios, core-location

i want to push notification when didupdatelocation method is called in suspended mode.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 0;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
-(void)sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:(NSString*)message
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = message;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    [self sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:@"hello"];
}
```

In a foreground it works fine but in suspended mode it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Do the Following

AppDelegate

1.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
```

2.Add this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
       UIAlertView *notificationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"message: notification.alertBody delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [notificationAlert show];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

3.Call Notification where ever you required

```
 UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
            localNotification.fireDate = date;
            localNotification.alertBody = @"Playing aiff sound";
            localNotification.alertAction = titleTextField.text;
            localNotification.soundName = @"b";

            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

i hope this will help you..

Comment: this is work only in background mode.. not in suspended mode.

Comment: i just want to push notification when application not running or not in background mode.